# How do I stop the ends of curtain poles (finials) falling off without making a hole in them?

Tags: home, adhesive

We've recently moved into a rented house in which we aren't meant to make holes in the fittings.

Several of the curtains are hung on wooden poles, like [these](https://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1600&bih=775&q=wooden%20curtain%20poles&oq=wooden%20curtain%20poles&gs_l=img.3...1174.4096.0.4753.20.10.0.10.10.0.88.687.10.10.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..1.19.720.zNaZLt2uFKk). The end curtain ring on each side is kept in position by being placed between the bracket holding up the pole and an end stop / finial. Only they aren't kept in position because the finials and the endmost curtain rings fall off whenever anyone opens the curtains in anything other than slow motion. The finials are not screwed on to the ends of the poles; they are meant to be held on by friction - only it doesn't work.

If we owned the house I would drill a hole through the side of the finial and hold the pole in place by a small screw, but as tenants we are not meant to drill holes in the landlord's fixtures.

Can anyone suggest a means of keeping the finials in place which does not mar them or the poles?

I have tried Blu-tack but it isn't very satisfactory, as the presence of a blob of Blu-tack on the side of the pole tends to make the finial go on awry, or stops it going on at all. If you roll out the Blu-tack very thin to prevent this, it shreds when you insert the pole into the finial and does not work at all. Putting the Blu-tack at the end doesn't work either, as there is a large gap between the end of the pole and the inside of the end of the finial.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: It seems like you have two problems: neither the outer ring or the finial are working correctly.  However, your blu-tack solution seems to address neither of these, it reads like you tacked the rod to the support.  Please clarify.  Can you post an image of your actual set up?   Btw, I'm thinking string or rubber bands will solve this.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question. No, the supports aren't involved; what I tried to use the Blu-tack for was sticking the finial to the pole. The finial is like a hollow cup into which the end of the pole is meant to be inserted. I can't post a picture right now (and actually I'm not sure how to post pictures), but I've edited the post to hopefully make it more clear that what is happening is that whenever the the curtains are opened with any vigour the outermost curtain ring clashes against the finial, knocking it off the end of the pole and causing the ring to fall off too.

Comment: Images are easy to do here.  Somewhere, there is a button that looks like a picture and you chick on it and choose your file.  SE takes care the hosting.

Answer (score 4):

Tie the outermost ring to the support.  There should be just enough slack that the ring isn't able to apply force to the finial.

Comment: that's a good suggestion with no damage or difficulty

Answer (score 2):

I would use a combination of string and tape. Use string to lock the outer ring to the support, so that it can't glide outwards and push the finial.

In addition I would add a few rounds of tape on the outer end of the rod itself so that finial stays on a little tighter. If not tight enough, add another round or two of tape!

Comment: good suggestion but tape will leave glue residue. See my altered suggestion that uses no adhesive.

Answer (score 2):

Use plumbers PTFE tape. Wind it tightly round and around the pole then squeeze the end ring and finial on, using a screwing motion for the finial in the direction you wound the PTFE tape (so you don't unwind it)

You can just pull it off when you leave, it won't budge, stick, set hard or stain and its very, very cheap at around £1 per roll.

Answer (score -2):

Use bubble gum or chewing gum.Take the finials out and wind used chewing gum around its end that asks for friction.Press it hardly to the pipe so that gum sticks onto it.

Comment: won't that set hard and stain the pole?